# What is the story of Performance Counters for .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net, linux, windows, .net-core

Under Windows, one is able to read .NET performance counters using the following:

- Performance Monitor
- C# using `PerformanceCounter`
- WMI and querying the .NET related classes

Considering the recent release of .NET Core and the fact that such app can also run in Linux, how can one access the .NET related stats currently available on Windows?

Comment: I believe it is open source, so you can search at GitHub.

Comment: there is an "Are perf counters available?" issue: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1319

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from making use of Windows-specific features when you are running on Windows. Sure, querying performance counters won't work when you deploy on Linux, but if you're not deploying on Linux, that's an irrelevant detail. Cross-platform is great, but flexibility is even better. Omitting features to achieve an ideal cross-platform system isn't really progress. You could [write the code yourself](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373083.aspx). Maybe eventually someone will write a module for Linux that implements Windows-style perf counters.

Comment: targeting Windows only is not an option as I need to also cover Linux. Writing the code myself is a `costly` option considering that it requires `C` and/or `C++` skills hence asking this question to clarify if there is any plan by Microsoft to provide a similar method of achieving what we already can do on Windows.

Comment: You can also subscribe to this issue: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/9376, the may or may not implement the performance counters infrastructure for desktop compatibility, it is marked as a feature.

Comment: Redhat being a contributor, I would like to see some use of [Performance Counters for Linux](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Developer_Guide/perf.html)

Comment: [Diagnose and solve performance problems in net-core](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-diagnostics-improvements-in-net-core-3-0/)...just an update for anyone that lands on here, these tools work for all OS'es [Example usage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77646439/7450780)

Answer (score 7):

This package is exactly equivalent of .NET Framework Performance Counters and can be used in .NET Core apps under Windows:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter/

Answer (score 3):

In the Windows Compatibility Pack for .NET Core will be support for Performance Counters

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/11/16/announcing-the-windows-compatibility-pack-for-net-core/

Of course, it is a Windows only feature for now.

Comment: May help other people but the OP specifically stated that the still wanted to target Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Performance counters are not in Linux thus not in NET Core. Create another "Full NET based helper application" to expose performance counters as service to "NET Core Application"

Comment: MaYaN already said that targeting Windows only is not an option

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use oracle tracing in linux.
Before make first connection write this:

```
OracleConfiguration.TraceFileLocation = "/app/trace";
OracleConfiguration.TraceOption = 0;
OracleConfiguration.TraceLevel = 1;
```