# CPU usage in .net core (at least on Windows)

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-standard

So `PerformanceCounter` is gone in dotnet core. I understand it was because it was not Linux-compatible.

This comment here: ( [What is the story of Performance Counters for .NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38124196/what-is-the-story-of-performance-counters-for-net-core#comment63707919_38124196) ) seems to suggest that if I was willing to run it only on Windows I could "make use of Windows-specific features", but I don't know how I could integrate that in dotnet core.

The reason I am willing to do this workaround is to keep the dotnet core codebase so I don't have to migrate once there is a cross-platform solution for `PerformanceCounter`.

So to summarize my question: how can I run the CPU usage in dotnet core when running on Windows?

---

**Other relevant posts that I've found:**

- [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45503285/831138) seems to suggest that `Process.GetCurrentProcess()` would be enough, which I don't quite understand (`PerformanceCounter`provided the full CPU usage for the machine).
- Looping through all processes (as [this other post seem to suggest](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/327#issuecomment-301615534)?) is not feasible (it throws an exception for some processes) and it looks pretty slow as well which is a problem for my use case.

Comment: We have ported the perf counter stuff from 4.7 to dotnet standard and we have made a start on a linux version too (in a branch)... it works well for our use case (primarily Windows at the moment) - https://github.com/Polystream/System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounters

Comment: @ScottPerham This is great! Thank you very much, it will be very useful.

Comment: Is there any reason not to use the official Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility package? https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility

Answer (score 2):

As of .NET Core 3.0, the Performance Counter APIs are once again part of the BCL and support Linux too:

- [MS: PerformanceCounters or equivalent are available in NETCore 3.0 and higher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.performancecounter?view=netcore-3.1)
- [MS DevBlog: Diagnostic improvements in net-core 3.0](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-diagnostics-improvements-in-net-core-3-0/)
- [SO: Linux example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59430961/get-large-object-heap-size-metric-using-net-core-running-on-linux)

Comment: There is an exception: PlatformNotSupportedException: Performance Counters are not supported on this platform. if using the PerformanceCounter class in .NET core 3.1