# Get "Large Object Heap Size" metric using .net core running on linux

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

How do I get the performance counter "Large Object Heap Size" running .net core (3.1) on linux (Ubuntu 18.04)?

Comment: ParisRoubaix I have edited the answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is LOH:

> The .NET Garbage Collector (GC) divides objects up into small and
>   large objects. When an object is large(>=85,000 bytes), it’s
>   considered a large object, actions like copying it in memory elsewhere
>   on the heap -- can be expensive.Because of this, the .NET Garbage
>   Collector places large objects on the large object heap (LOH).

Few approaches that can be explored for .NET Core Apps

1. For Windows Specific:

   Go to Performance Monitor > AddCounter > .NET CLR Memory > Large ObjectHeap Size > Select App Name
2. dotnet-counters:

   *dotnet-counters is a performance monitoring tool for .NET Core apps*

   Example Usage:

   `dotnet tool install --global dotnet-counters`

   `dotnet-counters monitor --process-id 1902 System.Runtime`

   https://github.com/dotnet/diagnostics/blob/master/documentation/dotnet-counters-instructions.md
3. dotnet-dump:

   *The dotnet-dump CLI global tool is way to collect and analyze
   Windows and Linux dumps all without any native debugger involved
   like lldb on Linux*

   `$ dotnet tool install -g dotnet-dump`

   `$ dotnet-dump collect --process-id 1902`

   `$ dotnet-dump analyze ./core_20190226_135850`

   https://github.com/dotnet/diagnostics/blob/master/documentation/dotnet-dump-instructions.md
4. dotnet-trace:

   *The dotnet-trace tool is a cross-platform CLI global tool that enables the collection of .NET Core traces of a running process without any native profiler involved*

   `$ dotnet tool install --global dotnet-trace`

   `dotnet-trace collect --process-id <PID> --providers Microsoft-Windows-DotNETRuntime`

   https://github.com/dotnet/diagnostics/blob/master/documentation/dotnet-trace-instructions.md

---

> How do I get the performance counter "Large Object Heap Size" running
>   .net core (3.1) on linux

### [image]

Other Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.gcsettings.largeobjectheapcompactionmode?view=netframework-4.8#System_Runtime_GCSettings_LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode

Comment: That one is an enum, anything to return the size of the LOH?

Comment: @ChrisO, interesting, In Windows we could open Performance Monitor > AddCounter > .NET CLR Memory > Large Object Heap Size

Comment: Yes, your edit about the `dotnet-counters` appears to answer the question.

Comment: @ChrisO, I have re-written the answer with more info, check it out