# .NET Core performance counters

Tags: .net-core, perfmon, contention

I have a .net core service running on windows. In the performance monitor tool I could find counters such as `"\Process(MyServiceName)\% Processor Time"` but not others like
`"\.NET CLR LocksAndThreads(MyServiceName)\*"`

how to find which .net core counters are supported by the perfmon?
I need to get the `"\.NET CLR LocksAndThreads(MyServiceName)\*"` for my service, any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Diagnose and solve performance problems in net-core](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-diagnostics-improvements-in-net-core-3-0/)

> Unlike the .NET Framework on Windows, .NET Core doesn’t emit perf
> counters. Instead, we had introduced a new way of emitting metrics in
> .NET Core via the EventCounter API.
>
> EventCounters offer an improvement over Windows perf counters as these
> are now usable on all OSes where .NET Core is supported.

[EventCounters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/event-counters)

> EventCounters are .NET APIs used for lightweight, cross-platform, and
> near real-time performance metric collection. EventCounters were added
> as a cross-platform alternative to the "performance counters" of .NET
> Framework on Windows.

You can use these performance diagnostic tools designed for .NET Core :

- [dotnet-trace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/dotnet-trace)
- [dotnet-counters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/dotnet-counters)

---

**Example Usage of dotnet-counters:**

1. Install the tool

   `dotnet tool install --global dotnet-counters`
2. Run command below to make dotnet-counters create a diagnostics
   socket  named `myport.sock` and wait for a connection.

   `dotnet-counters collect --diagnostic-port myport.sock`
3. Set `DOTNET_DiagnosticPorts=myport.sock` in your application's
   environment variables which will enable `dotnet-counters` to start
   collecting counters on your app and run your app.

Output of the command in 2:

[image]

---

By default `dotnet-counters` will collect/monitor the [Well-known EventCounters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/available-counters), The counters I believe you are specifically interested in are the [System.Runtime counters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/available-counters#systemruntime-counters) i.e `Monitor Lock Contention Count`,`ThreadPool Queue Length` and `ThreadPool Thread Count` (These are monitored/collected by default).